# An error occurs when closing the music bot

Tags: discord, discord.py, pycord

I am currently developing a music bot using library pycord (Previously it was discord.py).
I sometimes get the following error when closing the music bot.

```
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipe
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Broken pipe
Error writing trailer of pipe:1: Broken pipe
Error writing trailer of pipe:1: Broken pipe
```

This error indicates that there is still a voice connection.
But it is designed to connect from the voice channel at the end. (Disconnecting with the `cog_unload` function of the music player Cog.)
Why does this error occur?

Answer (score 0):

u need to do Disconnect the bot first from any voice channel before shutdowning its process or you can just ignore that error, that error willnot affect the bot because it was shutting down. thats is my oppinion, sorry if wrong spell or not helping answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).